# How to fire a function when selecting an idem in a dropdown in jSuites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown, onchange

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu with jSuites that fires a function once one of the items in the list is selected.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to fire the function. I tried with "onchange" both as attribute of the `<div>` and within the definition fo the jdropdown, but nothing seems to work.

I attach a fiddle here with a dropdown menu made with  that works and does what it should, and two jSuites menus that should behave in the same way but they don't...

What am I doing wrong?

Can this be done at all?

Any help is welcome...

http://jsfiddle.net/2x4qnj1h/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use that instead:

```
onchange: refresh_dropdown,
```

you used a literal, not a function.

Documentation with examples : https://jsuites.net/v4/dropdown-and-autocomplete/events